# ¿Cómo imprimir la línea anterior a un patrón con sed?

Tags: bash, sed

Tengo un fichero peliculas.txt con el siguiente formato:

```
Kong: La Isla Calavera
======================

(10/03/2017) [Estados Unidos, Vietnam]
Dirigida por Jordan Vogt-Roberts
Reparto: Tom Hiddleston, Samuel L. Jackson, Brie Larson...
   Un grupo de viajeros, exploradores y soldados de lo más dispar se reúne para viajar a una misteriosa isla del Pacífico que no aparece en los mapas. Entre ellos están el Capitán James Conrad (Tom Hiddleston), el Teniente Coronel Packard (Samuel L. Jackson) y una fotoperiodista (Brie Larson) amante de la naturaleza. Pero al adentrarse en esta bella y también traicionera isla, los exploradores encontrarán algo absolutamente sorprendente. Sin saberlo, estarán invadiendo los dominios del mítico Kong, el gigante gorila rey de esta isla. Será Marlow (John C. Reilly), un peculiar habitante del lugar, quien les enseñe los secretos de Isla Calavera, además del resto de seres monstruosos que la habitan...
1h 59min

Logan
=====

(03/03/2017) [Estados Unidos]
Dirigida por James Mangold
Reparto: Hugh Jackman, Patrick Stewart, Dafne Keen...
  Es el año 2029. Los mutantes prácticamente han desparecido. Un cansado y abatido Logan (Hugh Jackman) vive retirado en la ciudad mexicana de El Paso. Es una sombra de lo que era. Se gana la vida conduciendo limusinas y se emborracha más de la cuenta. Su compañero en el exilio es el Profesor Charles Xavier (Patrick Stewart), también en las últimas, ya que está enfermo, inválido y con sus facultades mentales deterioradas. Logan cuida de él. 
2h 17min
```

¿Cómo consigo mostrar el titulo de la pelicula?. Es decir mostrar algo similar a:

```
Titulo : Kong:La Isla Calavera
```

Debo usar el comando sed, y he conseguido que me muestre los titulos de las peliculas, pero no consigo que me muestra la cadena "titulo:(nombre pelicula)". He usado sed de esta forma:

```
echo -e "Titulo:$(sed -n -e '/^$/,/^=/p' $1)"
```

Y me muestra esto por terminal:

```
Titulo: Logan
=====
Es por tu bien
==============
El guardián Invisible
=====================
¡Canta!
=======
Red Army
========
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el patrón? Es decir, ¿el título aparece siempre encima de ===? Además, ¿cuál es el resultado que quieres para el fichero dado? Considera la importancia de leer [mcve].

Comment: Buenas, en efecto el titulo siempre aparece por encima de ===. Y quisiera que me imprimiera por pantalla lo siguiente: Titulo: Logan

Comment: ¿Pero quieres que imprima todos los títulos con el texto "Título:" delante o solamente uno de ellos?

Comment: Debo imprimir todos los títulos con el texto Titulo: delante.

Answer (score 1):

El problema aquí es que tu expresión `sed` extrae contenido, pero luego tienes una combinación `echo "Título"` +  `sed` que escribe "Título" seguido por todos los resultados de `sed`.

Para que funcionara con `sed` deberías hacer o bien un bucle sobre sus resultados, o bien alguna expresión compleja a partir de lo indicado en [Print previous line after a pattern match using sed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206887/40596).

Sin embargo, esto es pan comido para `awk`. Con él, si quieres escribir este texto al lado de cada uno de los resultados, simplemente debes decir:

```
$ awk '/^=+$/ {print "Título:", p} {p=$0}' fichero
Título: Kong: La Isla Calavera
Título: Logan
```

Esto busca las líneas que consisten solamente en `=`. Cuando eso ocurre, imprime la línea anterior guardada en una variable `p`. Además, también escribe lo de "Título".